# Programs fail to run after moving /home to a different partition on same drive

Tags: partition, troubleshooting, strace

I am running Arch and was having no difficulties until I moved my home dir to a different partition on the same drive.  The sequence of events:

1. Format other partition to ext4; mount it to /mnt
2. Move contents of /home to /mnt
3. Add new partition to fstab, mounted to /home
4. Log out, and back in.
5. All files accounted for

Initially there was some weirdness when I ran `startx`.  `xauth` was timing out trying to lock `Xsession`, but that seems to have resolved itself.  I have several programs (games) in my home dir that ran fine before the move, but won't run at all now.  No error, no blips/hiccups.  Nothing.

Here's an `strace`:

```
$ strace ./FTL
execve("./FTL", ["./FTL"], 0x7ffde9035740 /* 29 vars */) = -1 ENOEXEC (Exec format error)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/locale.alias", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2997, ...}) = 0
read(3, "# Locale name alias data base.\n#"..., 4096) = 2997
read(3, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en_US.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
fstat(2, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1076, ...}) = 0
write(2, "strace: exec: Exec format error\n", 32strace: exec: Exec format error
) = 32
getpid()                                = 11516
exit_group(1)                           = ?
+++ exited with 1 +++
```

I'm not sure what the issue is though.  It seems like, if the files are there after the move, then everything should be fine.  Does anyone else see what the problem is or have other ideas as to what the problem could be?

---

There are several programs that are doing this, but there are also other programs in my home dir that are running just fine.

---

**Update**: I have found the issue, but I don't understand what happened.  Perhaps someone can explain, or come up with a plausible theory.

The move didn't go as smoothly as I'd hoped, so I did a lot of `diff`'ing to check.  All files were present (or only on the new partition), so I thought I was good to go.  Checking today, I see that a number of files were 0 bytes.

```
mount /dev/sda6 /mnt
mkdir /mnt/allen
cd /home/allen
mv * /mnt/allen/
# got some "target dir is not empty" errors, so tried rsync
cd ..
rsync -var allen /mnt/
# did extensive diff'ing and file names look good; thumbs up?
sync
umount /mnt/
mount /dev/sda6 /home
```

This is roughly what I did.  I don't see where it went sideways.  I'm back up and running now, and having no issues, but if someone sees what caused some of the files to be 0 bytes, I'd love to learn something new.

Comment: What do you get when simply running `./FTL` directly not under strace? What does `file ./FTL` show you? Are you sure that file has execute bit set? Please share output of `ls -l ./FTL` as well...

Comment: Without `strace`, it does nothing.  Just returns to the prompt.  I'm not at that computer atm, so I'll have to check later, but IIRC it autocompleted the name after typing "./F", which I believe it only does it it's executable.

Comment: I'd imagine it would at least error out with `bash: ./FTL: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error` since that's what strace is complaining about... Anyways, when you manage to check this again, please update your question with more details. Thanks!

Comment: That would be a reasonable expectation, but it does not.  It does nothing, but return to the prompt.  There's not so much as a screen flicker.

Comment: It's odd that strace is getting this errno... We'll need more information to debug. Post also `ldd ./FTL` output (assuming it's a binary). Anything weird in logs, perhaps `dmesg` output?

Comment: You mean you rebooted, not just logged out and back in right?  Sounds like general file corruption during the copy.  I'd say either your ram or the disk is flakey.  Run a memtest86+ for at least 15 minutes.

Comment: You can help answerers by showing them exactly how the filesystem is mounted, both how it is configured in the fs table and what is actually reported by the `mount` command.

Comment: How did you move the contents of the partition?

Comment: I think the move was the problem.  I'll update the question with more details of the move, and if someone has a plausible explanation for what went wrong, please type it up in an answer.